# Entity Framework - DBUpdateException while updating entity

Tags: sql-server, winforms, entity-framework, exception

I'm stuck with a update problem using EF. During update from the WbsElement_All entity I get the following exception:

> Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.

I haven't any idea why I'm getting such an error, because the insert operation works properly.

The database structure looks as described on the picture.

[DB diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knANF.png)

Some explaination, that could be helpful:

- The data is stored in tables (Tables schema on diagram)
- The view are used to get data. Also the ef model is based on Views (Views are mapped to entities)
- CRUD operations are performed by using stored procedures. (Stored procedures are mapped in EF)

As you can see, the table Tables.ProgramWbs has ONE primery key, that is using TWO columns. The code looks as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [LTP2].[SAPProject](
[ProgramID] [int] NOT NULL,
[WbsElementLevel1ID] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_SAPProject] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[WbsElementLevel1ID] ASC,
[ProgramID] ASC
)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) 
ON [PRIMARY]
) 
ON [PRIMARY]
```

Also in this table is used the WbsElement defined in Tables.WbsElement (field PK_ID). So generally the table is resolving a many-to-many relation (many Programs can be assigned to many WbsElements and the same in the opposite direction). I have no idea why was this table designed in this way, but that's a different topic.

As said earlier in EntityFramework are mapped the views. So the definition is as follows:
1. WbsElement:

```
    public partial class WbsElement
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public WbsElementLevel1()
    {
        this.ProgramWbss = new HashSet<ProgramWbs>();
    }

    public int PK_ID { get; set; }
    public string WbsElement { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ProgramID { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ProgramWbs> ProgramWbss { get; set; }
}
```

2. ProgramWbs

   ```
   public partial class ProgramWbs
   {
       public int ProgramID { get; set; }
       public int WbsID { get; set; } 
       public virtual WbsElement WbsElement { get; set; }
       public virtual Program Program { get; set; }
   }
   ```

I think, that's for this moment all to describe the architecture. It's really strange, that this error occurs only while update. Insert works ok. 
The stored procedures are mapped properly. Basically the problem is somewhere on EF side (I think), because in SQL profiler I can't see any procedure call while update. So the error is recognized earlier.

The code, that generates the exception looks as follows:

```
var wbsElement = new WbsElement(){ Name="Dummy_1"}; 
this.Context.WbsElem‌​ents.Add(wbsElement); 
this.Context.SaveCha‌​nges(); 
wbsElement.Name="Cha‌​nged dummy name"; 
this.Context.SaveCha‌​nges();    //error statement
```

In the EF designer the primary keys are set up correctly.

Hope somone can give me a hint what's going on. 
Kind regards.

Comment: Please show the insert and update code. And does EF know about the proper primary keys? I.e. are they marked as primary key in the edmx designer?

Comment: Not in comments please. Edit your question.

Comment: Has somebody an idea?